# Server 2008 R2 Domain Controller MMC Crashes when Adding Role

Tags: server, active-directory, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008, mmc

I've searched around and have not been able to resolve my issue. The only thing I haven't tried yet that I've seen suggested is copying MMC Registry entries from a working server, mainly becaue I do not have an identically configured working server to copy from and don't really want to go through the trouble of creating one unless that is really my only option.

As stated in the title, I have a Server 2008 R2 domain controller that I am attempting to add the Active Directory Certificate Service role to. When I open the add role dialog, MMC crashes immediately after selecting the checkbox for the AD CS role. It does not crash if I select the checkbox for any other not yet installed role. If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated. I have deleted the cache as suggested in other forums. I have verified .net installations with the verification tool from Microsoft. And I have run the sfc tool, no errors were reported.

As I am not an IT guy by trade, if anyone is willing to assist me, I'll gladly re-run through any suggestions I've already tried or provide any additional data that may be helpful. Thanks.

Here is the text from the server manager log regarding the crash:

```
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:20.927 [CBS]                       IsCacheStillGood: True.
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:32.315 [Provider]                  System changed since last refresh: False
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:34.062 [CAManager]                 Test Initialization: CCertSrvSetup
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:34.202 [CAManager]                 Test initialization: True
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:35.388 [CAManager]                 Initialization: Creating CCertSrvSetup
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:35.404 [CAManager]                 Initialization: Initializing defaults
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:35.435 [CAManager]                 Initialization: Getting default key information
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:35.435 [CAManager]                 Initialization: Getting existing certificates
3208: 2017-10-04 16:01:35.466 [CAManager] Error (Id=0) An exception occurred at    at Microsoft.CertificateServices.Setup.Interop.CCertSrvSetupClass.GetExistingCACertificates()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.CertificateServer.CAManager.UpdateModel(Boolean certificateAuthorityAdded). Exception: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

And this is the text from the problem details dialog when the crash occurs:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: mmc.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 6.1.7601.23892
  Problem Signature 03: 5990c6ab
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 58e46330
  Problem Signature 07: 4227
  Problem Signature 08: a9
  Problem Signature 09: System.AccessViolationException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't been able to solve the issue with MMC. BUT, after digging around and piecing a variety of things together, I was able to install the role via some Powershell scripts. It appears to be installed and functioning at this point. I am now going to try to generate my SSL Certificates and wrap this all up. There were a few other things that I tried previously, but the one that seemed to do it for me was found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Setup-Certification-bd2aff3e).